# Invalid types Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, file, matrix, header

How do I pass a matrix as an argument between two function that are in different source files? (with their respective header file)

Do not worry about all the variables and arguments below.

```
//uex1010.cpp
typedef int Casilla;
void ejecutar(){
int tamanio, maxPuntos, numPiezas,puntActual=0;
    int fila, col, color, ancho, alto;//variables
    bool salir;
    fila=0;
    col=0;
    TipoTecla tecla;
    srand(time(NULL));
    if (entornoCargarConfiguracion(tamanio, maxPuntos, numPiezas)) {
        entornoIniciar(tamanio);
    }

    int i;
    entornoActivarCasilla(fila, col);
    salir = false;
    Casilla ocupada[tamanio-1][tamanio-1];
    comprobarCasilla(ocupada[tamanio-1][tamanio-1],col,fila,alto,ancho,color,tamanio);// I want to send "ocupada" to comprobarCasilla() in tablero.cpp
    //............
```

*tablero.cpp*

```
void comprobarCasilla(Casilla &ocupada, int col, int fila, int &alto, int &ancho, int &color, int tamanio) {
int i = 0, j = 0, colaux = col, filaux = fila;
while ((i < alto) && (ocupada[fila][col] == 0)) {//HERE
    col = colaux;
    j = 0;
    while ((j < ancho) && (ocupada[fila][col]==0)) {//HERE
        col++;
        j++;
    }
    fila++;
    i++;
}
if (ocupada[fila][col]==0) {//AND HERE it returns an error
    pintar(ocupada, colaux, filaux, alto, ancho, color);
}
```

}

The error is: `tipos inválidos ‘Casilla {aka bool}[int]’ para índice de matriz`

```
invalid types ‘Casilla {aka bool}[int]’ for matrix index
```

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef TABLERO_H_
#define TABLERO_H_
#include "entorno.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "pieza.h"

typedef int Casilla;

void iniciarTablero(bool salir);
void pintar(Casilla ocupada,int col,int fila,int &alto,int &ancho,int &color);
void comprobarCasilla(Casilla &ocupada,int col,int fila,int &alto,int &ancho,int &color,int tamanio);

#endif /* TABLERO_H_ */
```

Comment: A hint - always program in English.

Comment: A hint - I am spanish, I program in my language

Comment: That's not good practice. You should always program in English, which is the world-standard for programming, for any number of reasons, not least because it makes it much easier to get help on sites like this one.

Comment: Sorry, but there's not a spanish C++ or an english one, C++ is a programming languange. I think if you understand what are you doing doesn't matter the "language", furthermore the only things that change are the name of variables, functions and arguments(This ). Sorry for my bad english, and thank you anyway.

Comment: (This way is how i see it). Sorry for my bad english, and thank you anyway.*****

Comment: It is certainly your decision what language you write your own code. However, getting support in an international forum will be easier if you write in English. More important here would be that you reduce your example to a minimal example (i.e., remove all parameters which are unnecessary to illustrate your problem) -- especially for non-Spanish-speakers it is very hard to find the relevant parts, otherwise.